# How is spacetime locally Lorentzian at the center of a large mass?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature

Following up on the questions raise [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/609687/how-is-spacetime-locally-lorentzian) and trying to get a little more clarity on what it means to be 'local' and 'flat'.  In the first chapter of Gravitation, the author(s) state:

> The geometry of spacetime is locally Lorentzian everywhere

I can visualize this.  If I'm 8 light minutes from a large star, I can obviously see curvature in the path of a planet around that star, but if I take smaller and smaller measurements of shorter duration, so that for all intents and purposes I'm measuring a point on a geodesic around this star, then any experiment I do with test particles will meet the predictions of a Lorentzian geometry.

But I don't follow this logic if I do the experiment at the center of this mass.  If I do my experiment at the center of this star, then no matter how small I make my laboratory, even making it small enough to be considered a point, I'm still going to see curvature all around me.

How is the geometry of spacetime is locally flat at the exact center of a exceedingly large mass?

**Edit:** In trying to understand this statement from *Gravitation*, I'm trying to understand how a local geometry might not be flat.  An image of the geodesics around a singularity came to mind as a place on the manifold that wasn't differentiable.  This is the context for the question.

Comment: Related: [How is spacetime locally Lorentzian?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/609687/)

Comment: The phrase “center of curvature” does not have any meaning in GR. In general, spacetime is locally flat at every point *and* has curvature at every point. There is no contradiction because, as has been explained multiple times in response to your past questions, “*locally* flat” is very different from “flat”.

Comment: I hope you can step back and appreciate how contradictory that statement appears to someone trying to understand this subject.

Comment: Spacetime as a manifold is locally flat at the centre of a large mass because also there exists a tangent space with a Lorentzian metric.

Comment: It should be intuitively obvious that the surface of the Earth is “locally flat” but not “flat”. Spacetime works in the same way, but in four dimensions instead of two.

Comment: It seems somewhat strange to me that the place where local spacetime flatness troubles you the most — the center of a massive body — is the place where in Newtonian physics its gravitational force is *zero*.

Comment: @G.Smith - "*The center of a massive body is the place where in Newtonian physics its gravitational force is zero*". That's a good point.  The acceleration is greatest at the surface of the star and returns to zero at the center.  It's differentiable at that point.  I was thinking of a black hole where the center is a singularity that is not differentiable.

Comment: Note that while the force is zero at the center, the curvature is not. The right side of the Einstein field equations (the energy-momentum tensor) is nonzero there, so the   left side (the Einstein curvature tensor) is nonzero.

Comment: @G.Smith - Does the same logic apply to a singularity?

Comment: I think of various curvature invariants as becoming infinite as you approach a singularity (which means that at least some components of the curvature are becoming infinite). I don’t know how to think about the energy-momentum tensor at the singularity. I imagine that it doesn’t make mathematical sense to do so, but I’ll let someone else chime in on that.

Comment: @G.Smith - Thank you.  It's helpful for me (possibly others) to understand what "locally flat" means by understanding how something might not be "locally flat".  Continuing this discussion below.

Comment: From https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/144458/123208 "**A singularity in GR is like a piece that has been cut out of the manifold. It's not a point or point-set at all.** Because of this, formal treatments of singularities have to do a lot of nontrivial things to define stuff that would be trivial to define for a point set. For example, the formal definition of a timelike singularity is complicated, because it has to be written in terms of light-cones of nearby points." (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase "then no matter how small I make my laboratory, even making it small enough to be considered a point, I'm still going to see curvature all around me" is always true, no matter how far you are away from any star.

Spacetime is locally Lorentzian in a way similar to that a parabola can be locally approximated by a line. In no finite region will you find that the parabola is congruent to the line (unless it is a degenerate parabola of course). But you are guaranteed that you can find a line that concides with the parabola in one point and with the same slope.

Similarly you are guaranteed to find a Lorentzian metric and a connection that conincide in one point with the gravitational manifold.

Comment: Let me use this space to continue the thread of thought in the original post here.  If the mass was so great so as to cause a singularity, would you have a point on this manifold that was not differentiable?  Would the geometry at this point be locally Lorentzian?

Comment: In an essential singularity the metric and connection are, by definition singular, and hence, have no value which could be considered locally Lorentzian at all. But in a conventional star there is no essential singularity. Probably a coordinate singularity, but then you can always choose suitable coordinates to make it disappear.

Comment: Thank you.  Between you and G. Smith I've figured out that 1.) I was getting a coordinate singularity mixed up with a physical singularity.  This can be fixed by choosing another coordinate set. 2.) The geodesics around a normal mass are differentiable, they don't approach a physical singularity at the center of the mass. 3.) The local geometry of spacetime is not Lorentzian at a singularity.  Have I got that right?

Comment: @GluonSoup: as to 3): take the simple hyperpola $f(x)=1/x$ as a basic metaphor: you can't approximate it by a line at $x_0=0$ because that would require $f(x_0)$ and $f^\prime(x_0)$ to be be defined. By contrast, $f(x)=x^2/x$ is also singular at $x_0=0$, but this singularity is removable (similar to a coordinate singularity) and then you can approximate it by $x$ at $x_0=0$ even if it is not defined there. Locality in $locally Lorentzian$ is defined by the metric and it's derivatives/connection. If they are not defined in the point of interest, you're  in trouble with applying that definition.

Comment: as to 2) if you mean by "normal mass" an extended mass and not a point mass, then the metric, the connection, and the geodesics are differentiable and so it is meaningful (and true) to talk about them being locally Lorentzian.